Why does the navbar not take the theme I am trying to assign
I have a app at https://stackblitz.com/edit/etnmae-xjweyt and cannot seem to get it to compile much less assign a neutral color to the navbar.
I can change it from light to dark mode, but want something other than a light pink as the background.
this is the style, an in the same folder i have my m3-style.scss.  I am NOT using any Material 2 styling, strictly Material 3, so I don't need backward compatability.
enter code here

@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'm3-theme.scss';

$typography-config: (
  plain-family: 'Edu AU VIC WA NT Pre',
  brand-family: 'Edu AU VIC WA NT Pre',
); !

$typography-config-secondary: (
  plain-family: Roboto,
  brand-family: Open Sans,
  bold-weight: 900,
  medium-weight: 500,
  regular-weight: 300,
);

$theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
    typography: $typography-config,
  )
);

$theme-secondary: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: mat.$violet-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$magenta-palette,
    ),
    typography: $typography-config-secondary,
  )
);

body {
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;

  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  @include mat.toolbar-theme($theme-secondary);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
//THIS Is what I am trying to use for the toolbar and I have a toolbar theme above that doesn't work either  
mat-toolbar {
  background-color: mat-color($neutral, 900); // Adjust the shade as needed
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme); // <- notice!

Any assistance would be appreciated
Thanks

I notice that you are not using the custom theme you created, so I modified the code to use the custom theme.
@use "m3-theme.scss" as custom-theme;
...

...
$theme-secondary: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: custom-theme.$primary-palette,
      tertiary: custom-theme.$tertiary-palette,
    ),
    typography: $typography-config-secondary,
  )
);

To configure the customization, please follow the below steps, angular material got new upgrades on version 19 and it makes theming 100 times easier.

First visit the documentation page, for you it's mat toolbar - documentation then visit the styling tab.

Here at the bottom you will find Tokens supported by toolbar-overrides which contains the tokens for customization of the toolbar. Since we are customizing the background color, we choose container-background-color.

Now we have the token name, we can refer the new Theming guide using component tokens then add the mat.<<feature name>>-overrides( method to add the custom styles. To get the theme color I use the mat.get-theme-color and configure the token with this obtained property.
 mat-toolbar {
   @include mat.toolbar-overrides(
     (
       container-background-color:
         mat.get-theme-color($theme-secondary, neutral, 96),
     )
   );
 }



After this your have customized your navbar based on a overridden theme.
Full Code:
@use "sass:map";
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "m3-theme.scss" as custom-theme;

$typography-config: (
  // <- notice!
  plain-family: "Edu AU VIC WA NT Pre",
  // <- notice!
  brand-family: "Edu AU VIC WA NT Pre",
  // <- notice!
); // <- notice!

$typography-config-secondary: (
  plain-family: Roboto,
  brand-family: Open Sans,
  bold-weight: 900,
  medium-weight: 500,
  regular-weight: 300,
);

$theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$magenta-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$violet-palette,
    ),
    typography: $typography-config,
  )
);

$theme-secondary: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: custom-theme.$primary-palette,
      tertiary: custom-theme.$tertiary-palette,
    ),
    typography: $typography-config-secondary,
  )
);

body {
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;

  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  @include mat.toolbar-theme($theme-secondary);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

mat-toolbar {
  @include mat.toolbar-overrides(
    (
      container-background-color:
        mat.get-theme-color($theme-secondary, neutral, 96),
    )
  );
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme); // <- notice!

Stackblitz Demo

you are the man of the evening.  I have been fighting this forever.  I am new to angular and theming, so the documentation didn't make too much sense.  I notice most of the examples re a mix of M2 and M3.  The documents don't specify 2 or 3, so it's really hard to know what pattern I was following.  I will definitely remember this question when I have to remember the process.  Thank yoi very much

I need to ask one more question, In terms of scope for the style.scss, my assumption is that it is global to the app.  However when I move the mat toolbar override token to navbar.component.scss, it can't find $theme.  I thought it would inheret those properties

@Rogeri You have to use @use "../../styles.scss" as theme; import and specify the relative path to access the theme, angular style files are scoped to the specific component only

so every component must import the styles.scss? seems a bit odd to me.

@Rogeri if you define the styles at the global level, there is no need to do this, like how we have scoped the toolbar styles to happen only for mat-toolbar, you can use the component selector app-my-navbar { material styles here... } to prevent these imports, else you have to import the theme in order to use it. scss is modular, import to use it

thank you very much, I appreciate your time
